# Java event - Class type of e.getSource error

Tags: java, events

I have this bit of code:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;

....

Table table = code_that_returns_table_object;

table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
  public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    Table table = e.getSource();
  }
});
```

It seems apparent that the source of the event should be a Table object, yet when trying to compile I get this error:

```
incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table
          Table table = e.getSource();
```

If I do this:

```
table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
  public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.getSource().getClass());
  }
});
```

Output prints "org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table"

Can anyone tell me why I am getting the incompatible types error, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The [`getSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) method is declared as returning an object of type `Object`. You need to use

```
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    Table table = (Table) e.getSource();
}
```

if you are certain it will be a `Table` object. Because the `Object` can be anything else, the compiler prevents from assigning references that aren't compatible.

Comment: thanks, that takes care of it.  If I can figure out how to mark your answer as "the one", I'll do that.

Comment: @user2512168 You're welcome. You can upvote it with the little arrow or you can check the checkmark to accept it.